# Is the Polis tower a remnant of the lost Polaris station?

Tags: the-100

Could it be what's left of the space station Polaris (having been shot down, and maybe crashing to Earth)? Flip this picture...

[image: Polaris station in space]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It's not clear (to me anyway) what your question is.  Are you trying to ask if this space station is what becomes the tall round building in Polis?  Please read [ask] for pointers about writing a good question.

Answer (score 1):

## Nope.

Shortly (like, a couple minutes) after the Polaris station got destroyed by Alpha station, Becca lands on what's about to become Polis, and the tower is already here. That's not enough time for the Polaris station to crash right before the pod arrives, the dust falling back down, Grounders carving all those windows (which are absent from the station, see the picture in the question), etc.

Additionally, what's left of the Polaris station is most likely lost.

In season 3, episode 8 "Terms and Conditions", when A.L.I.E. attempts to find the remnants of Polaris, to get her hands on A.L.I.E. 2.0, she and Raven calculate that Polaris likely fell into the ocean:

> JAHA: How sure are you that the debris from the Thirteenth Station fell into the ocean?
>
> RAVEN: A.L.I.E. and I ran the trajectories a thousand times, literally a thousand times.
>
> JAHA: But what is the actual probability that you're right?
>
> RAVEN: Between 75% and 80%.
>
> JAHA: Not good enough. Keep looking.
>
> RAVEN: I told you, this is as good as it gets.

After that the plan is to boost A.L.I.E.'s processing power by wiring more minds into the City of Light, but that gets thwarted by Raven stopping to trust A.L.I.E. upon realising the latter removed her memories of Finn. So we don't have a *stated* 100% certainty of what happened to the Polaris debris, but it's probably just gone forever:

- Raven and A.L.I.E. were already pretty sure the debris did fall into the ocean, and they're easily the two smartest people on the show;
- oceans cover 70% of the Earth's surface (per [National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/encyclopedia/ocean/)), so you're already left with... not that much space to land on;
- entry in the atmosphere would likely have deteriorated the Polaris station too much to be salvageable.

Comment: Personally, that last point pretty much obviates the entire question.  There's no way anything like that survives an uncontrolled re-entry, much less lands intact perfectly vertically without pancaking.  And even if it _did_, it still wouldn't stand up, since nobody builds an orbital structure to withstand that kind of compressive load.

Comment: @DavidW we're talking about a show where [worldwide nuclear storms of doom spare one tiny valley](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/195660/98028), cryosleep kinda works, radiation mutates you in ~1 second, hacking is a matter of typing speed, and by the way, at least two stations survived borderline-uncontrolled space re-entry mostly fine. I love this show, but you've got to forget science exists watching it :D Also (spoilers), aliens.

Comment: @Jenayah Wait what? Aliens in The 100??

Comment: @Roberto back when I wrote this answer, season 5 had finished​with the crew in space, heading for an unknown planet. I thought there'd be aliens. There kind of were (local fauna and all), but in the end, indeed it was mostly humans

Comment: Right! Didn't check the date :P